# Invisible Collision Ocject

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone.

I  want to add the BOX in the world, and added the box(by getKnownObjectNames())
But, they are invisible, so I can see they fron RViz2.

- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- ROS2 Humble

Mesh files from xacro/stl is visible... I cannot understand why BOX is invisible.

```
moveit_msgs::msg::CollisionObject obj;  
obj.header.frame_id = mg->getPlanningFrame();   
obj.id = "BOX";

shape_msgs::msg::SolidPrimitive prim;  
prim.type = shape_msgs::msg::SolidPrimitive::BOX;  
prim.dimensions = {2.0, 2.0, 2.0};     
geometry_msgs::msg::Pose pose;     
pose.position.x = -2.0;  
pose.position.y = -2.0;    
pose.position.z = -2.0;  
pose.orientation.w = 1.0;

obj.primitives.push_back(prim);  
obj.primitive_poses.push_back(pose);  
obj.operation = moveit_msgs::msg::CollisionObject::ADD;

moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface ps;  
ps.applyCollisionObject(obj);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413363/invisible-collision-ocject/) by [Jaye](https://answers.ros.org/users/133389/jaye/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2023-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved. not displayed "Planning Scene" in RViz2.

---

Originally posted by [Jaye](https://answers.ros.org/users/133389/jaye/) with karma: 16 on 2023-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0